# Flickering Mesh Problem: DirectX HLSL

Tags: c#, hlsl, flicker, directx-9, managed-directx

**The Problem**: I am rendering a mesh using HLSL *(High Level Shader Language)* in Managed DirectX 9.  Depending on the complexity of the mesh *(number of vertices and faces)* I sometimes get problems with flickering.

Obviously a mesh with higher complexity should take longer to render, and the amount of flickering increases with the complexity of the mesh. However, what occurs is the mesh isn't rendered *at all* and the time it takes to draw the mesh *is significantly lower*.

`Increased Mesh Complexity -> Increased Flickering`

**The Code**:

```
/* Before this is called: 
     - The Device has been set up successfully
     - The Effects have been compiled successfully
     - The RenderState is correct, etc.. etc..
*/

public void Draw(Device device, MyMeshClass mesh)
{
    // Set vertex/index buffers (this has been timed, negligible)
    CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured[] vb = mesh.Vertices;
    short[] ib = mesh.Indices

    // Set shader parameters (this has been timed, negligible)
    this.effect.SetValue("texture", mesh.Texture);
    this.effect.SetValue("color", mesh.Color);
    this.effect.SetValue("worldViewProj", mesh.ViewProjection);

    int passes = this.effect.Begin(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < passes; ++i)
    {
        this.effect.BeginPass(i);
        device.DrawIndexedUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, ib.Length, ib.Length / 3, ib, true, vb);
        this.effect.EndPass();
    }
    this.effect.End();
}
```

**Results**: This is the output I get *(I inserted timers which are not included in the above code for readability)*:

```
// This is a Copy/Paste from the debug output
.
.
Draw Mesh: 1.2851 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.3882 ms
Draw Mesh: .4819 ms     // <-- It flickered here
Draw Mesh: 1.3638 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.4972 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.4262 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.2239 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.6684 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.6963 ms
Draw Mesh: 2.3397 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.3484 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.4012 ms
Draw Mesh: .5287 ms     // <-- It flickered here
Draw Mesh: .4644 ms     // <-- It flickered here
Draw Mesh: 1.6140 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.4392 ms
Draw Mesh: 1.4579 ms
Draw Mesh: .4987 ms     // <-- It flickered here
Draw Mesh: 1.4873 ms
.
.
```

**HLSL Code**:  Here is the *abbreviated* HLSL code, please note that this is NOT the actual code so don't dig into syntax errors, I assure you the actual code is extremely similar.

```
Texture texture;
sampler TextureSampler; // There is more here, I cut it out to save space
float4x4 worldViewProj : WorldViewProjection;
float4 color;


float4 mainVS(float4 pos : POSITION) : POSITION
{
    float4 Out = mul(pos, worldViewProj);           

    return Out; 
}

float4 mainPS(float4 pos : POSITION) : COLOR
{
    float4 Out = tex2D(TextureSampler, pos.xy);

    return Out;
}


technique Standard
{
    pass One
    {
        CullMode = CCW;
        AlphaBlendEnable = true;
        SrcBlend = SrcAlpha;
        DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;

        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 mainVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 mainPS();
    }
}
```

Any help / ideas / suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a `VertexBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` and render using `DrawIndexedPrimitives`